# Tor on a usb stick

Tags: tor-install

Must admit to not being a much of a technical wizard at this point, although I worked as a tech support person for years before I retired.

Yet, I have spent many HOURS (nothing else to do right now) trying to put Tor on a USB memory stick (PNY 32GB) so I can just plug it in and navigate to it and run Tor. Sounds simple, but the best I can do is only to get it to work on the computer from which I do the install. If I try it on another computer (same version of Windows) it seems to try to work and brings up a window with the address bar, the rest is all white and fails to load the starting window content.
Any suggestions?

Regards,
Bill Waters

Addendum: Tried installing Tor on the second computer (mentioned above) and had exactly the same problem, so it is some sort of compatibility problem...

B.W.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)

Tails is a live operating system that you can start on almost any computer from a USB stick or a DVD.